# image opacity level to 100%

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend, blend

I have an image that I am using as a button but on the mouse enter I want the opacity to be 100%, which at this point is only 80%. How would I do that?

here is my mouse enter event

```
private void playButton_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            double x;


        }
```

I am using blend, silverlight 4
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your event is being "hit"...

```
private void playButton_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if ( sender is Button )
      ((Button)sender).Opacity = 1;
}
```

that said, you should also respond to the mouse out event and set the opacity back to .8

you could use the visual state manager to do this as well. [here is a nice example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it all in XAML.  This requires the [Blend SDK for Silverlight 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3062) (which actually does not require Blend, so don't be misled if you don't have or use Expression Blend).  Assuming you started with something like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Image Source="Penguins.jpg" Opacity="0.8"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You could transform it into something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Image Source="Penguins.jpg" Opacity="0.8">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```